# While implementing paypal-rest-sdk I am getting access-allow-Origin error

Tags: node.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing PayPal in my project and I am using **paypal-rest-sdk** and follow this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k03jobKGXM

While doing `res.redirect()`, on the front end I am getting:

> redirected from `localhost:8000/api` from origin `null` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource.

**API which I am calling:**

```
var create_payment_json = {
    ...
    ...
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error... ',error.response);
      throw error;
    } else {
      console.log('successs... ', payment);
      for (var index = 0; index < payment.links.length; index++) {
        //Redirect user to this endpoint for redirect url
        if (payment.links[index].rel === 'approval_url') {
          // console.log('approval url... ',payment.links[index].href);
          res.redirect(payment.links[index].href);
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

**main app.js:**

```
const cors = require('cors');
var enableCORS = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, token, Content-Length, X-Requested-With,Accept, *');
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, token, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Accept, *');
  next();
});
app.use(enableCORS);
cors({credentials: true, origin: true})
app.use(cors());
```

I am able to call other APIs from my front end and while doing `res.redirect()` for PayPal I am getting this error.

Comment: Not sure if you were able to solve this but I was getting same error and setting cors did not help. So using the solution listed in this link - essentially dont do redirect at sever but ruturn the url to client browser and then open it from there - https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/How-to-fix-preflight-error-when-calling-Billing-API/m-p/558696#M37003

Comment: Thank you.. @MalkitS.Bhasin

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I could solve it.
Paypal provides the button code as a form with an action. My problem was that I had changed:

```
form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
```

to

```
action="javascript:myCheckFunction"
```

where I performed some cross check and then called jquery $.post function to post the request to PayPal.
Paypal did not like this :-) I changed back to the original "action=" code, and moved my cross checks elsewhere (which worked)
Hope this helps.